# Cosa sono i "pantaloni a saltafosso"?

Tags: meaning

Nel romanzo *Pane e tempesta* di Stefano Benni ho letto:

> C'era il Nonno Stregone, naturalmente, con due dita di toscano che gli sporgevano dalla bocca, e la vecchia giacca color ex beige, **pantaloni a saltafosso**, calzini corti spaiati e sandali da legionario.

Non capisco cosa sono i "pantaloni a saltafosso". Ho cercato il termine "saltafosso" in parecchi dizionari, ma non ho trovato niente che possa fare riferimento a dei pantaloni. Una ricerca su Google mi ha fatto vedere che si tratta di un'espressione che si usa spesso. Me lo potreste spiegare?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I **pantaloni a saltafosso** hanno la caratteristica di essere di una lunghezza intermedia tra quelli definiti corti e i normali pantaloni lunghi.

Da [il Principe Totò](https://books.google.it/books?id=vq4VTuID1GkC&pg=PA6&lpg=PA6&dq=pantaloni%20a%20saltafosso&source=bl&ots=bdwFo-cxFn&sig=BC4_h207CNppeCjBOJf0szV9Av8&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiEw7HclK7WAhVHtRQKHatyC40Q6AEIVTAL#v=onepage&q=pantaloni%20a%20saltafosso&f=false) di Orio Caldiron:

> Totò si costruisce pezzo per pezzo: la bombetta, un paio di ***pantaloni
>   a saltafosso***, delle scarpe sfondate.

In questo caso danno al personaggio una connotazione comica.

[image]

Inoltre, dalla rubrica [Scioglilingua del Corriere della Sera](http://forum.corriere.it/scioglilingua/05-01-2011/saltafosso-per-eta-beta-1690424.html)

> ***Saltafosso*** mi fa ricordare lo "zumpafuosso" napoletano che indicava
>   sia un gioco infantile sia i pantaloni molto corti (vi ricordate i
>   pantaloni di Totò?) che in Toscana trova l'equivalente con il modo di
>   dire "che c'hai l'acqua in casa?"

Il senso del modo di dire è che avendo l'acqua in casa i pantaloni lunghi si sono bagnati e di conseguenza ristretti, oppure che sono stati risvoltati per evitare che si bagnino e quindi risultano più corti.

Comment: Più che ristretti, io ho sempre pensato che si riferisse all'averli risvoltati più volte, ma posso sbagliare.

Comment: In effetti forse sarebbe meglio dire accorciati

Comment: @DaG: Nel mio paese, in questa situazione, a volte si scherza con la domanda "vai a pescare?" Io ho sempre pensato che facesse riferimento al fatto di cercare di non bagnarsi i pantaloni con l'acqua portandoli così.

Comment: Aggiornata la risposta a seguito dei suggerimenti